# C# - .MapResultAsync Not Working + DisplayHelp not working with Async

Tags: c#

I am using the C# CommandLineParser Library but I stumble upon some problems regarding async custom Help display.

I have the following problems:

- I want to implement the custom help function (code below)

  ```
   private static async Task<int> DisplayHelp<T>(ParserResult<T> result, IEnumerable<Error> errs)
   {
       var helpText = HelpText.AutoBuild(result, h =>
       {
           h.AdditionalNewLineAfterOption = false; //remove the extra newline between options
           h.Heading = "Myapp 2.0.0-beta"; //change header
           h.Copyright = "Copyright (c) 2019 Global.com"; //change copyright text
           return HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(result, h);
       }, e => e);
       Console.WriteLine(helpText);
       return -1;
   }
  ```

In the Main code I have the following problems:

- When using the `.MapResultAsync` it does not work
- When using the `.MapResult` function it does work, but not the part I want (code below):

  ```
   static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
   {   
       var parserResult = new Parser(c => c.HelpWriter = null);
       return await parserResult.ParseArguments<AddOptions, CommitOptions, CloneOptions>(args)
         .MapResult(
           (AddOptions opts) => RunAddAndReturnExitCodeAsync(opts),
           (CommitOptions opts) => RunCommitAndReturnExitCodeAsync(opts),
           (CloneOptions opts) => RunCloneAndReturnExitCodeAsync(opts),
           errs => DisplayHelp<Task>(parserResult, errs));
   }
  ```

The main problem is that errs does not properly want to process the Task `parserResult`, because `parserResult` is not a `CommandLine.ParserResult` object.

So my questions are:

- How to I convert the parserResult to the `CommandLine.ParserResult` object?
- How to properly call the `DisplayHelp` method.
- How to properly make both of them Async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix to the problem.

```
internal static async Task CLCLPE(string[] args)
    {
        var parser = new Parser(p => { p.AutoVersion = false; p.CaseInsensitiveEnumValues = true; });
        var parserResult = parser.ParseArguments<AddOptions, CommitOptions, CloneOptions>(args);
        await parserResult.MapResult(
                (AddOptions opts) => RunAddAndReturnExitCodeAsync(opts),
                (CommitOptions opts) => RunCommitAndReturnExitCodeAsync(opts),
                (CloneOptions opts) => RunCloneAndReturnExitCodeAsync(opts),
                errors => Task.FromResult(DisplayHelp(parserResult, errors)))
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to Continue...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            });
    }
```

The if statement Debugger is optional and can be removed if needed.

The help function would look like this:

```
 //Help with Synchronous Operation
    private static int DisplayHelp<T>(ParserResult<T> result, IEnumerable<Error> errs)
    {
        var helpText = CommandLine.Text.HelpText.AutoBuild(result, h =>
        {
            h.AdditionalNewLineAfterOption = false;
            h.AddNewLineBetweenHelpSections = true;
            h.AddEnumValuesToHelpText = true;
            h.AutoVersion = false;
            h.Heading = CommandLine.Text.HeadingInfo.Empty;
            h.MaximumDisplayWidth = 110;
            //  h.AddVerbs(typeof(SyncOptions), typeof(QueryOptions), typeof(TokenOptions));
            return h;  // only h
        });
        Console.WriteLine(helpText);
        return 1;
    }
```

Since the help function is not an async method it does not need to be executed async.